# Can we use superdense coding with unentangled pair of qubits?

Tags: entanglement, superdense-coding

In transferring information through the means of superdense coding, entangled pair of two qubits is used. Can we use superdense coding with unentangled pair of qubits too?

Comment: I guess the whole idea of superdense coding lies on the infomation theoretic benefits of having entangled qubits.

Comment: Superdense coding by definition uses shared entanglement. Did you mean, without shared entanglement, whether you can send 2 classical bits by communicating one qubit?  The answer is no, as the Holevo bound suggests you can communicate at most 1 classical bit by sending 1 qubit.

Comment: @Abir Thank you, understood